# Phrase for perniciously expensive

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase that expresses something (or a decision) being expensive by costing money in many small bits (perniciously) rather than being a large single cost.

Comment: *They’ll **nickle-and-dime** you*.

Comment: Death by a thousand cuts

Answer (score 2):

@Dan Bron's suggestion of ***nickel-and-dime*** is a good one.  Per the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[nickel-and-dime](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nickel-and-dime)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> *North American*
> *informal*
> Harass (someone) by charging for many trivial items or services.
>
> *‘we don't nickel-and-dime our customers like some vendors that charge extra for every little utility’*

It is perhaps a better answer than what I thought of: ***penny wise and pound foolish***.  The Oxford Dictionaries describe it thus:

> ***[penny wise and pound foolish](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/penny_wise_and_pound_foolish)***
>
> **PHRASE**
>
> Careful and economical in small matters while being wasteful or extravagant in large ones.

If you try to save money in the short run, you'll end up paying a lot more over time.

Note: a *[nickle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_green_woodpecker)* is green; a *[nickel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel)* is a silvery-white metal (or a coin traditionally made of this metal).